# Naming conventions for class and/or interfaces in terms of TAP

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, naming-conventions

I am currently stock in the subject referenced design issue.

Otherwise good TAP guides around the net does not answer my question; should interfaces and/or classes be prefixed with Async the same way asynchronous methods should be suffixed (eg. `CopyToAsync`).

However, in terms of Microsoft ASP.NET Core, I can sometime see, that interfaces is prefixed with Async, eg. `IAsyncActionFilter`, where a synchronous variant is named `IActionFilter`.

I kinda like the idea of this convention, but I am unsure if it is an industrial standard now?

What if the interface has a mixed content of async and sync methods?

What is best practise and what do you guys currently practise?

With this question in mind, I really miss an updated version of **Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries** from Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Abrams.

But until that dream come true, I hope for excellent input from all of you great Stack-minds.

Comment: You're unlikely to get an authoritative answer, and will probably have to go with precedent and opinion.  The `Async` prefix seems appropriate for an Async version of an existing synchronous interface, but it's not clear that it would be a universal best practice.  I don't see anything wrong with an interface that exposes both synchronous and asynchronous members.

Comment: I think it would be fairly rare for an interface or class to be *purely* async in nature, or where it's the most important feature of the type. `IAsyncActionFilter` may be the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it would seem you have a valid point. Of the entire API Reference at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/, 5 interfaces emerges to the surface. However, the Core team has some interesting patterns that I hope will be adopted by the community. Thanks for the comment.